# No Platforms Available for elastic beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I login into AWS console through AWS educator account. When I am trying to access Elastic Beanstalk service, its saying that I don't have permission for that. Please see attached [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67VXl.png) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the role you are assuming (s3674204) has the correct IAM permissions to access EB. For example, by adding this to the policy:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticbeanstalk:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```